# htaccess doesn't work after moving from webhost to local Synology host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, synology

I have a hosted website where I use the following htaccess file for formatting of urls, These all work fine. The host uses Apache, but unfortunately doesn't show a version number. I think it's 2.4.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/(.*) /item.php?item=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*) /showitems.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /searching.php?options=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^searching/(.*) /showitems.php?search=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^update/(.*) /showitems.php?update=$1 [L]

AddType application/x-httpd-lsphp .html .htm .shtml
```

I copied the entire site to my local Synology Diskstation with Apache 2.4.

The rewrite urls for category, search and update work fine. However, the urls for 'searching' and 'item' return 404 errors. 'Searching' is a header redirect from within 'searching.php'

Item is an oddity in the sense that it uses 2 get params in the result url. In trial and error mode I changed it to:

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*) /item.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Which doesn't work either, however

```
RewriteRule ^itemitem/(.*) /item.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Works fine, which really puzzles me. This last rewrite also doesn't work when I add the second parameter again.

What am I missing? Or is there a better way to approach these rewrites in the first place that I could try?

Comment: Try and disable MultiViews, that is usually the culprit in such situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What CBroe has commented on your post is properly the correct answer.
To be more specific and explain why then if your Apache 2.x server has MultiViews enabled it will try to match things up for you like directory names, file names on your behalf to make the user-experience easier.

However, this can in many cases confuse your rewrite rules that are expecting very specific regular expressions.

In most cases you can get away with just disabling MultiViews.
You disable it by adding to your Options in your .htaccess file.

```
-MultiViews
```

Please note that if the AllowOverrive directory does not allow this then your need to change the Apache configuration file for that vhost/directory to include the -MultiViews option.

You can read more about MultiViews here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

The other thing and perhaps more correct way is to build your rewrite rules better and take advantage of things like the "!-f" or "!-d" parameter to let your rules know that you don't want to include files or directories and so forth.

A side note by the way on MultiViews, even though it's very fancy and neato - If you are running a production site please know that MultiViews create a hole lot of unwanted disk I/O and can slow down the Apache servers performance quite a bit! So it's always good practice to disable MultiViews.